# Customizing Spring Session

Tags: spring-boot, spring-session

I am using Spring Boot with Spring Session for storing session data. Users log in to the application with Spring Social. As a result, the saved security context has a SocialAuthenticationToken. This means that other web apps sharing the session data need to use Spring Social and also have access to the social tokens.

What I'd like to do is save the `sessionAttr:SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT` with a token that is available through Spring Security only. Furthermore, I'd like to add a second Redis key for the social information.

Where are the extension points for adding this kind of customization to Spring Session? I would like it to be as unobtrusive as possible.